# HTTP delete message using requests module

Tags: python, http, python-requests, http-delete

I am using the `requests.delete` as follows:

```
r=requests.delete(url, json.dumps(data))
```

This gives me the following error:

```
r=requests.delete(url, json.dumps(data))
TypeError: delete() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`requests.delete`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.delete) function has the following signature:

```
requests.delete(url, **kwargs)
```

There's only one required positional argument, `url`, and the rest should be keyword arguments, the same as for [`requests.request`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.request) function.

Your `json.dumps(data)` then surely doesn't give proper format of keyword arguments. If you just want to pass this JSON as data, do:

```
requests.delete(url, data=json.dumps(data))
```